# Why an int type of object and a number can not be added?

Tags: c#, variable-assignment

I have a int type variable which is derived from object and when I tried to sum this variable with a number can not sum them. Even though both of them are type of System.Int32 why I can not sum. What is the reason of this ?

Here is my codes:

```
        object number_1 = 34;
        number_1 = number_1 + 10;

        Console.WriteLine(number_1);
```

Comment: Type incompatibility for operations is the reason. Only valid operations between types are allowed. C# being statically typed language needs type information at compile time. It will work if you change object to dynamic, which is run time verification. Languages like Python is dynamically typed.

Comment: It is not allowed because it is (obviously) nonsense. To do it you need to cast to `int` i.e. explicitly state that you know what you are doing. Note that `object` is able but not not meant to hold any type! There is hardly ever a good reason to declare anything as `object`.

Answer (score -1):

You can not sum number with object

it is better :

```
            object number_1 = 34;
            int numb1 = (int)number_1 + 10;

            Console.WriteLine(numb1);
```